# 3-way / 4-way round-robin tournament scheduling algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, round-robin, tournament, sports-league-scheduling-problem

I would like to create/implement a tournament scheduling algorithm which is able to deal with more than 2 participants per game.

The problem seems to be well known for 2 participants. See here for example: [Round Robin Algorithm Implementation Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471421/round-robin-algorithm-implementation-java)

Example of matchups with 6 teams (A, B, C, D, E, F):

1. (ABC)(DEF)
2. (ABD)(CEF)
3. (ABE)(CDF)
4. (ABF)(CDE)
5. (ACD)(BEF)
6. (ACE)(BDF)
7. (ACF)(BDE)
8. (ADE)(BEF)
9. (ADF)(BCE)
10. (AEF)(BCD)

In case of an odd number of teams (i.e. A, B, C, D, E), I would like to have a 3-way and a 2-way game per round: (ABC)(DE)

Once the 3-way problem is solved, I would like to do the same with 4-way games.

I am unable to create such an algorithm and unable to find a similar solution on the internet.

Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To choose K items from N, you need [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Note that `C(6,3)=20` but you do fixing one item (A) and have really `C(5,2)=10` variants

There is a lot of implementations of combinations generation - the simplest is [recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n#16256122), more effective is [lexicographic ordered generation  -simple C code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#Lexicographic_ordered_generation)

Comment: Thank you for the references. I am not sure if I really fix one item (A). I just sorted it that way. My numbered lists stands for "rounds" where 2 games can be played in parallel. Each game is represented with the teams in parenthesis, so I actually have 2x10=20 items, right?

Comment: The set in the first team defines set in the second, so they (20 items) are not independent. About fixing: generate combinations (5,2) using BCDEF set, then add A to combination of two items.