# Given an array of size n, find a way to arrange it such that no two side-by-side index pairs match for n-1 different arrays (team scheduling)

Tags: java, arrays, combinations, unique, schedule

I have a simulator in Java in which I am trying to create a schedule of unique team matchups for a given sports league. In soccer, each team will play each other exactly ONCE with the first numTeams-1 matchweeks.

For example, in a 20 match league, there will be 19 matchweeks. In all 19 matchweeks, team 0 will play a unique team {1,2,3,4,...19,20}. Team 1 will play a unique team each week {0,2,3,4,..,19,20}, etc., up until the 20th team who will play teams {0,1,2,3,4,..18,19}.

For simplicity, I wrote my algorithm to select two side by side index pairs using a random shuffle of the array {0,1,2,..19,20}. If my generated array was {6,4,11,1,...0,18}, the pairs following would be {(6,4),(11,1),...(0,18)}. The next matchweek, i would shift all even values twice left, in this example leaving an array {11,4,13,1,...,0,6} and the resulting pairs for that week would be {(11,4),(13,1)...(0,6)}. Continuing this pattern (numTeams/2) times, we will get the first 10 unique weeks (in a 20 team league).

To finish the latter 10 matchweeks, I made a brute force method where I would generate a new random array of the 20 teams, and use the same shifting to generate the full 10 weeks. I would then run a test on  the whole 20 matchweeks and see if a collision occurred, and if it did, the calculation would rerun, else it would return the final array.

This did not work, and I cannot think of a good way to generate a second half of the matchweeks. If their is a flaw in working with the first half I have, I should change that too. Regardless, any tips to help solve this problem would be appreciated.

In the code below, each time the test fails I rerun the entire thing, not just the latter matchweek half, but neither method is able to exit the loop quickly.

```
public Integer[][] uniqueMatchGenerator(int numTeams){
    Integer[][] randomIndicies = new Integer[numTeams-1][numTeams];

    //returns array of random unique numbers from 0 to numTeams
    randomIndicies[0] = randomIndexArray(numTeams, null);

    //FIRST half of pairs
    for(int i=1;i<(numTeams-1)/2;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<numTeams;j++){
            if(j%2==0){ //even shift
                randomIndicies[i][j] = randomIndicies[i-1][(j+2)%numTeams];
            }else{
                randomIndicies[i][j] = randomIndicies[i-1][j];
            }
        } 
    }

    //second half of pairs
    randomIndicies[(numTeams-1)/2] = randomIndexArray(numTeams, null);

    for(int i=(numTeams-1)/2+1;i<numTeams-1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<numTeams;j++){
            if(j%2==0){ //odd shift
                randomIndicies[i][j] = randomIndicies[i-1][(j+2)%numTeams];
            }else{
                randomIndicies[i][j] = randomIndicies[i-1][j];
            }
        } 
    }

    boolean failed = false;

    //brute force test

    //for each matchweek
    int i =0;
    while(i<numTeams-2){
        //for each pair in our arrays
        int m=0;
        while(m<numTeams&&!failed){
            int[] checking = {randomIndicies[i][m],randomIndicies[i][m+1]};
            System.out.println("checking {" + randomIndicies[i][m] +","+randomIndicies[i][m+1]+"}");
            int k=1;
            while((k<numTeams-1)&&!failed){
                int j=0;
                while(j<numTeams&&!failed){
                    int[] against = {randomIndicies[k][j],randomIndicies[k][j+1]}; 
                    System.out.println("against {" + randomIndicies[k][j] +","+randomIndicies[k][j+1]+"}");
                    if(Arrays.equals(checking,against)){
                        System.out.println("FAILEDFAILEDFAILEDFAILEDFAILEDFAILED ");
                        failed = true;
                    }j=j+2;
                }k++;
            }m=m+2;
        }i++;
    }

    if(failed){
        return uniqueMatchGenerator(numTeams);
    }else{
        return randomIndicies;
    }
}
```

I would like to have one, no-collision group of unique parings. I was not able to find success with this method.

Comment: [Round-robin tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471421/round-robin-algorithm-implementation-java

Comment: If you are doing this for an actual league, and not for a programming assignment or practice problem, there are pre-prepared round-robin schedules.